# Does doing a core upgrade from 4.5 to 4.7 using wp core update include the security & maintenance release of 4.6.1? How can I tell?

Tags: wordpress

Security & Maintenance release by Word Press are usually automatically applied, but in this case I did an upgrade of several versions at once by the command line. Is the security and maintenance release included in this command? Where can I look to find out whether or not it is included?

Comment: If you're at 4.7 you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With releases, you have minor releases such as `4.6.1` where the `.1` is the minor release.  And then you have major releases, such as `4.7`.  Each release builds upon the other.  Therefore, `4.7` includes the releases prior to it.

> Is the security and maintenance release included in this command?

To answer your question, yes, the `4.6.1` release is included in the latest version, i.e. [WordPress `4.7.1` Vaughan](https://wordpress.org/news/2016/12/vaughan/).